# passing variable from activity to custom created view

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass a String variable from my activity to my custom created view class. I have tried Bundle but it does not seem to work.I want to pass the value of the input of the EditText called 'destination'in my MainActivity to my DrawView class. What I am trying to achieve is depending on the user input in the activity class the DrawView class will draw the shapes in a different position Any help would be appreciated.

This is the code for my activity class

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    static EditText destination = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.roomdinput);
    String roomName;
    //DrawView drawView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final Button floorPlan = (Button)findViewById(R.id.floorPlanButton);        



floorPlan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v){


    roomName = destination.getText().toString();
    Bundle myb = new Bundle();
    myb.putString("key", roomName);
    Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DrawView.class);
    a.putExtras(myb);
    startActivity(a);
    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.helloworld3.FLOORPLAN"));



}   

});

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And this is the code for my DrawView Class

DraView.class

```
public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    float ux, dx, rx,lx;
    String roomName2;
   Bundle myb2 ;


    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawLine(90, 250 , 90, 400, paint);
            canvas.drawLine(20, 0, 0, 20, paint);
            canvas.drawCircle(150, 400, 30, paint);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't use `startActivity(...)` to 'start' a class which extends `View`. You'll need to either pass the data in the constructor of your `DrawView` or, if you need to update it regularly, create a method in your `DrawView` class which can be used to pass data into it and which then invalidates / redraws the view itself.

Answer (score 3):

As far as you have `DrawView` extended from `View` , you can simply use `setTag` method to pass object to view. Why not to use this useful feature ?

```
SomeCustomObject obj = new SomeCustomObject();
myDrawView.setTag(obj);
```

and in view you can get tag using `getTag` method.

```
SomeCustomObject = (SomeCustomObject)getTag();
```

Of course you can declare method or constructor in your `DrawView` class

Like

```
public class DrawView extends View {
    SomeCustomObject obj ;
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    float ux, dx, rx,lx;
    String roomName2;
   Bundle myb2 ;
// Custom constructor
public DrawView(Context context,SomeCustomObject object) {
        this(context);
        this.obj = object;
    }

// Custom method
public void setObject(SomeCustomObject object) {
     this.obj = object;
}
    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawLine(90, 250 , 90, 400, paint);
            canvas.drawLine(20, 0, 0, 20, paint);
            canvas.drawCircle(150, 400, 30, paint);
    }

}
```

If you have your `DrawView` in another activity and you want to pass data to it, firstly you should pass it via Intent , than get object from intent in second activity , and after that pass this object to your `DrawView`. If you need an example, just say.

Comment: Why are you defining an object to pass as a parameter to the constructor and setter method of the `View`? That's over complicating things - if you look at the OP's code they simply want to pass a `String`.

Comment: I have provided two possible ways to do this, but of course not using them together.

Comment: And of course it would be better to use interface for this purpose. But it this case the task is to pass some data to the custom view.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call view object and setContentView

```
drawView = new DrawView(this);
setContentView(drawView);
```

Additionally if you want to pass `parameters` pass through creating `setter` methods in your `View`